# Snakemake how to execute downstream rules when an upstream rule fails

Tags: snakemake

Apologies that the title is bad - I can't figure out how best to explain my issue in a few words. I'm having trouble dealing with downstream rules in snakemake when one of the rules fails. In the example below, rule spades fails on some samples. This is expected because some of my input files will have issues, spades will return an error, and the target file is not generated. This is fine until I get to rule eval_ani. Here I basically want to run this rule on all of the successful output of rule ani. But I'm not sure how to do this because I have effectively dropped some of my samples in rule spades. I think using snakemake checkpoints might be useful but I just can't figure out how to apply it from the documentation.

I'm also wondering if there is a way to re-run rule ani without re-running rule spades. Say I prematurely terminated my run, and rule ani didn't run on all the samples. Now I want to re-run my pipeline, but I don't want snakemake to try to re-run all the failed spades jobs because I already know they won't be useful to me and it would just waste resources. I tried -R and --allowed-rules but neither of these does what I want.

```
rule spades:
    input:
        read1=config["fastq_dir"]+"combined/{sample}_1_combined.fastq",
        read2=config["fastq_dir"]+"combined/{sample}_2_combined.fastq"
    output:
        contigs=config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/contigs.fasta",
        scaffolds=config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/scaffolds.fasta"
    log:
        config["log_dir"]+"spades/{sample}.log"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        """
        python3 {config[path_to_spades]} -1 {input.read1} -2 {input.read2} -t 16 --tmp-dir {config[temp_dir]}spades_test -o {config[spades_dir]}{wildcards.sample} --careful > {log} 2>&1
        """

rule ani:
    input:
        config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/scaffolds.fasta"
    output:
        "fastANI_out/{sample}.txt"
    log:
        config["log_dir"]+"ani/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        """
        fastANI -q {input} --rl {config[reference_dir]}ref_list.txt -o fastANI_out/{wildcards.sample}.txt
        """

rule eval_ani:
    input:
        expand("fastANI_out/{sample}.txt", sample=samples)
    output:
        "ani_results.txt"
    log: 
        config["log_dir"]+"eval_ani/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        """
            python3 ./bin/evaluate_ani.py {input} {output} > {log} 2>&1
        """
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to allow spades to fail without stopping the whole pipeline and you want to ignore the output files from spades that failed. For this you could append to the command running spades `|| true` to catch the non-zero exit status (so snakemake will not stop). Then you could analyse the output of spades and write to a "flag" file whether that sample succeded or not. So the rule spades would be something like:

```
rule spades:
    input:
        read1=config["fastq_dir"]+"combined/{sample}_1_combined.fastq",
        read2=config["fastq_dir"]+"combined/{sample}_2_combined.fastq"
    output:
        contigs=config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/contigs.fasta",
        scaffolds=config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/scaffolds.fasta",
        exit= config["spades_dir"]+'{sample}/exit.txt',
    log:
        config["log_dir"]+"spades/{sample}.log"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        """
        python3 {config[path_to_spades]} ... || true
        # ... code that writes to {output.exit} stating whether spades succeded or not 
        """
```

For the following steps, you use the flag files `'{sample}/exit.txt'` to decide which spade files should be used and which should be discarded. For example:

```
rule ani:
    input:
        spades= config["spades_dir"]+"{sample}/scaffolds.fasta",
        exit= config["spades_dir"]+'{sample}/exit.txt',
    output:
        "fastANI_out/{sample}.txt"
    log:
        config["log_dir"]+"ani/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        """
        if {input.exit} contains 'PASS':
            fastANI -q {input.spades} --rl {config[reference_dir]}ref_list.txt -o fastANI_out/{wildcards.sample}.txt
        else:
            touch {output}
        """
        
rule eval_ani:
    input:
        ani= expand("fastANI_out/{sample}.txt", sample=samples),
        exit= expand(config["spades_dir"]+'{sample}/exit.txt', sample= samples),
    output:
        "ani_results.txt"
    log: 
        config["log_dir"]+"eval_ani/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        """
        # Parse list of file {input.exit} to decide which files in {input.ani} should be used
        python3 ./bin/evaluate_ani.py {input} {output} > {log} 2>&1
        """
```

---

**EDIT** *(not tested)* Instead of `|| true` inside the `shell` directive it may be better to use the `run` directive and use python's `subprocess` to run the system commands that are allowed to fail. The reason is that `|| true` will return 0 exit code no matter what error happened; the `subprocess` solution instead allows more precise handling of exceptions. E.g.

```
rule spades:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        ...
    run:
        cmd = "spades ..."
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell= True, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr= p.communicate()

        if p.returncode == 0:
            print('OK')
        else:
            # Analyze exit code and stderr and decide what to do next
            print(p.returncode)
            print(stderr.decode())
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it seems like it makes sense. Then in my rule all I could have as input "output.exit" rather than the spades output, so I have stored somewhere which spades jobs have already run and failed, and snakemake will not try to run them again if I execute my pipeline more than once.

Comment: I think it makes total sense @dariober. As a general rule, I guess `||` can be coupled with any command which we are sure will not fail. I was thinking one can exploit this feature to run a "plan B" if the first command does not work. Is this correct?

Comment: @Geparada I think you are right about running the plan B but see my edit to the answer. Basically, I think it would be better to use `|| true` sparingly to avoid ignoring genuine errors. (My solution above with subprocess can probably be improved)

Comment: This is very cool. I did not know the `subprocess` library and it looks very useful to avoid scripting in bash. Last question: Do you know if within `run` you can access objects from the global scope of the Snakefile? For example any variable defined before the rule `spades`? Thanks a lot for the update.